# What spell did Julia use at the begining of the Magician King?

Tags: lev-grossman, magician-king

One of the first scenes of the book is during the hunt of the rabbit that can see the future, when they find that strange clearing and their friend (don't remember the name right now) dies after going through it.

When that happens, Julia casts a spell immediately and one of the side effects, is that she ends up with pitch black eyes. Do we ever find out what was the spell trying to do and what other effects did it had on her?

I'm getting to the middle of the book right now, so if we find out the answer further down, then just say so, or post it under a spoiler tag, otherwise, please do tell, because it's driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At the same time the clearing filled with a ghostly green light - a bleak, alien spell of Julia's that Quentin still didn't get the details of, or even the broad outlines of, that was intended to reveal any bad actors who might be present.  It turned her eyes all black, no whites or iris at all.

No, the particulars of the spell are not discussed further in the novel.  The key point here is that Julia's magic is completely unrecognizable from anything taught at Breakbills.  Quentin can often recognize bits of magic from *hedge* witches as having roots in the magic he was taught.  Julia's is on another level altogether.

The source of her magic and what she goes through to obtain it are revealed throughout the book.

Comment: Well the, I guess that'll have to suffice then. Thanks for the answer :)